# How would healing potions affect our medical system?

Tags: internal-consistency, medicine, medical, dungeons

In my story, dungeon entrances have appeared all over the world (modern earth setting) telling the world to prepare for 'bad things' which will start in 5 years (that is what they are told). Discovered within them apart from the typical monsters, mana stones, and metals, were potion ingredients. When cultivated in our world, they still grow and people can make them into effective healing potions.

I more or less have an explanation on what happens to our world if they discovered mana stones as an alternate power source.

But I am unsure on how we would react to game like healing potions?

These potions are the typical game ones, take enough and even broken bones can be healed. After about a half a year, a cure potion  is discovered which even cures cancer. After another year, another potion is discovered leading to the recovery of lost limbs and the such. Effectively, **this means that there is no incurable conditions on earth**. Of course there will be a supply and demand period for a while but after it stabalises...

My question for this is:

As all of the medical sectors jobs have been taken over by these potions making their expertise and facilities no longer needed, **what would happen to the global health sector?**

Comment: You are asking three different questions please limit yourself to one question per post. Questions asking *what would be the effect of x on society?* are often closed as too broad.

Answer (score 3):

Good luck getting the potions through the FDA approvals process!!

All kidding aside, just ask yourself what happened to the people who once did any job that is now redundant. The jobs no longer exist, so anyone who might have done those things now does something else. Once enough potions come along, there will probably be a period of chaos within the health sector. Of course Big Pharma will probably react most harshly. Corporate Medicine will also react harshly and so will the insurance industry. These entities thrive and make their billions on the fact that people get sick and need treatments.

Ordinary nurses and even doctors will probably (deep in their hearts) feel an impending relief that people will no longer have to suffer illness or injury. But they'll also feel the stress of impending job loss (more so physicians).

In the US, about 20% of the GDP goes into healthcare; 10% of the population is working in healthcare. That's a huge blow to any economy. It's not just nurses and physicians either. It's hundreds of thousands of technicians, medical assistants, receptionists, engineers, housekeepers, nutritionists, cooks, caterers. And it's not just people that work in hospitals, it's companies that make medical supplies & equipment, it's technicians that keep that equipment working and truck drivers and loading dock folks and stock keepers that make all those supplies flow. It's contractors who are always around maintaining the facilities, it's tens of thousands of police officers who maintain security (hospitals generally have special law enforcement officers on staff).

That's a lot of people who will suddenly be on the dole or seeking unemployment benefits. You might, ultimately, be looking at a crash or a serious depression in civilisation.

As for #3, I can't imagine anyone would want to see a regular doctor when all they need to do is drink a purple potion and all their problems disappear!

All this, of course, assumes that the potions just kind of appear (as if by magic!) the way they do in games, ready to use and everyone knows what they're for.

If it's raw ingredients, then at the least you'd still need physicians to diagnose illness and determine which potion is best. You'ld still need someone to grow and process the ingredients. You'ld probably still need some nurses to administer and watch over patients while they're recovering.

And of course, you know darn well Uncle Sam will want to tax and regulate the hell out of this new industry!

Answer (score 1):

Your questions is mostly opinion-based and you could write any approach - it depends on your goals and story-line.

In my opinion, after some time of instability a new features will be integrated in life. Portions would live on with usual medicine.

---

**TLDR**

1. Health sector would got impulse and start growing faster and faster
2. Most professions would remain. Some of them require less personal and some attract new ones. A new areas would appear
3. Many people couldn't afford new medicine, some people would ban for different reasons and some imagine that everything could be solved by potions (in fact, not all)

---

### Stratification of society

In our life some people are starving and another suffer from obesity. Some couldn't survive and some get help by charity and this the only reason they still alive. And they both live in the same country. For homeless man a cure for cancer is needless. He easily change it for the dinner. So my point is **only richest people could get cure for anything** they need. Just rich could get almost all and middle class could get potion from broken leg but couldn't afford cure for hepatitis. Compare to the present: someone has cured for cancer, another live with HIV for decades and some died from pneumonia.

### The frequence of potions

In many games more powerful potions are more infrequent. F.e. one potion for cancer could be met for 1,000 potions for Alzheimer's disease and 1,000,000 for dysentery. When someone got glaucoma he have **choice**: to find out and **pay for a potion or** go to a surgeon or **just wear the glasses**. Many people don't ready even for surgeon for many reasons (not only money but also religious, fear, timing and "it's good enough with glasses").

Also most powerful potions are situated in dangerous places, at least in games. In safe placed they would be collected in some days and traded for something that people really need.

### Limited knowledge

I bet potions are found without instruction and don't have caption "I'm for  headache". Society need people who study the potions, identify and classify them. So it would lead to **new professions arisen**. Those professions would become part of medicine.

### History examples

Consider a gold rush. Somewhere people found gold in large amounts and... The old gold mines are still was working, some people became rich, some bankrupted and some just died. A new jobs was arisen, new mines opened and some regions were populated. But most changes was local and gold still cost more than copper - just because **there are more people** than <s>gold</s> healing potions.

Penicillin was discovered in 1929 and came into commercial use in 1942 (dozen years later). It didn't eliminate infectious diseases hospitals but brought up a new area of medicine. It also has side effects so there are many alternatives novadays.

There are many novels in which the world experienced some external, unpredictable and mysterious factors. My favorite one is [Roadside picnic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roadside_Picnic).

Answer (score 0):

Big Pharma would immediately "patent" the stuff, package it, dispense it in small drops at very high prices.

You will need a proper prescription to get one.

Someone will have to decide what potion is suitable for you.

Business as usual.

... until Narcos take over.